# Foreach in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach, each

I have been asked to find the minimum age in each rating from a table, which looks like this:

```
table name: 'SAILORS' 
fields: 'SID', 'SNAME', 'Rating', 'Age**'
```

This can be done using PHP, but I have to do this using a MYSQL Query.

Comment: Review [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). This is a rudimentary example.

Comment: In general very little detail about the problem but if I unserstand your question correct. You  search for a simple select like: 
`SELECT rating, min(age) as min_age
FROM sailors
GROUP BY rating`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [group by](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php) over `Rating` column and [min](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function call will do it.

```
SELECT Min(`Age`)  AS `Lowest Age`, 
       `Rating` 
FROM   `SAILORS` 
GROUP  BY `Rating`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select Rating, min(Age) as MinAge
from SAILORS
group by Rating
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple query with a group by:

```
select Rating, min(Age) from SAILORS
group by Rating
```